# while sending some data in node js socket, having issue

Tags: node.js, sockets

while sending data in sockets in nodejs, sometimes i am getting below issue

```
node:20) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined.
```

I'm not sure what has caused this issue, can anybody help me with this issue.
thank you...

Comment: my node js version : v6.10.1

Comment: node will warn you if you don't handle a Promise rejection. In your case somewhere in your code you have a <somevar>.message that causes an exception (because <somevar is undefined) in a Promise chain inside your code.